# How to delete any dynamically created file from solution?

Tags: c#, file, io

I am creating a file into the solution's directory as below:

```
var targetPathToCreate = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "FolderName");

DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(targetPathToCreate);

if (!dirInfo.Exists)
{
    dirInfo.Create();
}

var filePath = Path.Combine(targetPathToCreate, "FileName");
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytesArray);
```

and further I am sending this document via email and then trying to delete this document.

For that I tried this code:

```
System.IO.File.Delete("FilePath");
```

but this line throws an exception:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Is there any way to delete the files by overcoming the exception?

Comment: Are you try to close VS, or reboot?  It's realy too difficult to search what program is uses your file. I often use "reboot" as solution.

Comment: Actualy my requirement is to generate some files, send them as attachment in email and after an email sending i have to delete those files.so for this scenario VS reboot is not an option.

Comment: There is not all code? I thing you are not uses "using(MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream()) {...} "

And not close files. In some another place

Comment: You can read about it here. https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2019/04/09/using/

It's work with disposable objects and auto close all files when program exit from using block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use garbage collector's [WaitForPendingFinalizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers?view=netframework-4.8) function.
It will suspend the current thread until the thread that is processing the queue of finalizers has emptied that queue.

```
   if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
      System.GC.Collect();
      System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
      System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    }
```

If this doesn't work, you have to dispose your mail object.

```
mail.Attachments.Add(...);
smtpServer.Send(mail);
mail.Dispose();
System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
```

Comment: Got same result?

Comment: yes
System.IO.File.Delete(filePath); line throws the same exception.

Comment: I updated my answer. You have to dispose your mail object. Better if you use both as a combination :)

Answer (score 0):

I took a look and noticed that the error is possibly generated because your code `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytesArray);` may not be finished in its execution.

Here is a [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-copy-delete-and-move-files-and-folders) you can look at. You could also get the newly generated file's name by writing a new method that mails it and then deletes it, which could include something like this:

```
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\MyFiles\" + yourfilename + "'");
        try
        {
            fi.Delete();
        }
```

Comment: the code you have suggested is not throwing an exception but also not deleteing the file

Comment: Have you tried the using statement, which disposes of the objects? As well, as a previous poster suggested, you probably have to use WaitForPendingFinalizers.